# How can I extract a PDF/SWF file from an EXE?

Tags: windows-7, extract

I have a book which is inside EXE, how can I extract the PDF file from EXE?
universal extract not working. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pxzw3y0ppSrHFkCMTM0jTDe1sdLKCrf_/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I extract the PDF file from EXE?

You can't, there's no PDF inside.

Comment: Thanks Sir. how do I print questions/page ?

Comment: screenshot only

Comment: @Junme https://yadi.sk/i/6kxIifPs3ZwjoN  can i easily make it like this ?

Comment: @TomBrackman like this https://yadi.sk/i/eer4rMkw3a2bBn  screenshot and make pdf

Comment: @Junme Thanks Sir. But your pdf very good quality my pdf not good https://we.tl/BjA8MxQc6F why ?

Comment: @TomBrackman most probably because I use 5K monitor

Comment: Thanks Sir @Junme. can I ask one more question ? ı have one .swf file and ı am print this file https://we.tl/JiNxF32cKI

Comment: Each thread in SuperUser should be a single question with answers to that question. If you have additional questions, please use the Ask Question button to ask them as their own thread. Also, once someone has answered your question correctly, please use the Checkmark icon next to that answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: @music2myear ı am sorry my mistake